# Django, JavaScript: When passing 'null' to front end, JS turns it into &39;null&39;

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, django, null

I have a view that is passing a 2D array to my front end:

```
return render(request, self.template_name, {'runs': runs, 'graph_data': graph_data})
```

Where **graph_data** contains arrays of [x, y] coordinates, and occasionally it needs arrays of [null, null] to mark breaks in my line graph (using flot.js)

```
graph_data = [ [1, 7], [2, 9], [null, null], [5, 2], [6, 4] ]
```

When building this 2D array in my view, I insert breaks like this:

```
    other stuff happens
else:
    graph_data_total += array
    graph_data_total += ['break']
```

Basically, when I need to insert a line break in my graph, I insert the graph array, followed with the string 'break' with string concatenation (+=).

Then, I need to convert datetime.datetime objects to milliseconds (the X coordinate in each individual array), so I go over each point and do that, unless it's a "break", in which case I need to insert [null, null], **without** quotes:

```
for point in z_scores_total:
    if point != 'break':
        time = point.time
        graph_data.append([unix_time_millis(time), point.parameter_value])
    else:
        graph_data.append([json.dumps(None), json.dumps(None)])
```

The JSON documentation states that `json.dumps(None)` would insert **null**, without quotes, [as seen here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Except I'm seeing **['null', 'null']** if I **print(graph_data)**, which ends up in my front end as described in the title, **[&39;null&39;, &39;null&39;]** making the whole thing crash.

Ideally I need to insert None with json.dumps so that it turns into **null** WITHOUT the quotes, or make it so that JS doesn't for some reason convert the single quotes into "**&39;**"

Would anyone know why **json.dumps(None)** is inserting single quotes, and why those **single quotes get decoded to their ascii values** when they reach my front end?

Comment: You need to show what else is in graph_data, how you are passing it to the template and how you are outputting it there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `None` value in JSON, so `json.dumps` uses the string `'null'`.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(None)
'null'
```

Then you insert the resulting `graph_data` into your template and it probably gets automatically escaped. `&39;` is the HTML escaped value for `'`. You probably need to mark the sting as safe, using [Django's mark_safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe).